# Construct url that search youtube mobile

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube

I am trying to construct youtube search url to be executed on UIWebViewC. It seems to be something like this

http://m.youtube.com/#/results?q=test

but it always bring me back to youtube mobile home.

anyone can provide any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://m.youtube.com/results?q=test

or, use the RSS version:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=rss&racy=include&vq=BBC+Five&start-index=201&max-results=50

Comment: this will not work if I open with `TTWebController` I will get a invalid username. Similarly, trying to add # in between will just lead me to home screen

Comment: Thanks. If I couldn't find a better answer I'll accept yours. :)

Comment: Both answer and question are now outdated.